# how to interpret service command output

Tags: scripting, services

```
/usr/sbin/service --status-all 

 [ ? ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  bootlogd
[...]
```

apparmor service looks like it's running, right?
but:

```
/usr/sbin/service apparmor status | grep apparmor

apparmor module is loaded.
```

my question: Can I take for granted that apparmor service is running (because it's loaded in kernel). Is there any way it can be loaded but not running, or not running properly?

I am asking this question because, when using a script and you want to know if a particular service is running or failed, it's easier to use

```
/usr/sbin/service "${SERVICE}" status | grep "${SERVICE}"
```

(I grep to have a short answer)  than

```
/usr/sbin/service --status-all
```

The later command gives a bulk output which is quite difficult to manipulate.
I certainly missed something but there is pretty much nothing in the service man page.

Any ideas folks?

Comment: What OS is this? There isn't any need to pipe the output into `grep service` afterwards.

Comment: OS=Devuan; if no grep, the output is very long; with grep, I have got only 1 line in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looking at the output, you should check `service`’s exit code:

```
if service apparmor status >&/dev/null; then echo AppArmor is loaded and enabled; fi
```

This needs to run as root to provide accurate results.

And yes, given the truncated output in your question, AppArmor is loaded and enabled. There is no corresponding process because AppArmor is entirely handled in the kernel; the initscript only loads the necessary profiles.